# prevent TabBarLayout from going under StatusBar

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How do I prevent TabBarLayout from going under StatusBar?

FYI: I set my CollapsingToolBar to `scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed`. And I set the ToolBar to `snap|exitUntilCollapsed`.

Comment: can you provide your remaining xml too as there are many reasons that cause partial snapping

Answer (score 1):

android:fitSystemWindows="true"